# npm flag --no-optional is still downloading optional dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

I can't get the `--no-optional` flag to work when I have `"optionalDependencies": { "foo": "0.0.1"}`. I also see the threads for this not working in 2018 are closed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your package-lock.json. I would recommend you do a `rm -r node-modules` and a new `npm install`.

Comment: Are you saying I should do `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm install --no-optional`?

Comment: @MaxCoplan correct that's what I'm saying. so you use the `npm install --no-optional` as needed but you need a new install so the package-lock picks up that there are optional dependencies